# Changing NSDate at 6pm instead of Midnight

Tags: ios, time, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I wanted to know if was possible to change the NSDate that is displayed in a UILabel at 6pm instead of midnight? So if today is December 12th, at 6pm on december 12th the UILabel will show December 13th.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Probably no straight-forward way.  Simplest would be to format the date and time strings separately, and increment the source NSDate (in a temp copy) before formatting the date.

Comment: The supposed duplicate isn't a very good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter* fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";  // And locale, timezone, etc
NSDate* tempDate = [theDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:6*60*60];
NSString* dateString = [fmt stringFromDate:tempDate];
fmt.dateFormat = @"HH/mm/ss";
NSString* timeString = [fmt stringFromDate:theDate];
NSString* theFullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", dateString, timeString];
```

(Written without testing, so there's likely a tupo in there somewhere.)